# bash date environment variable

Tags: bash, date, environment-variables

I need to calculate a date using a date string, derived from command line variables in a bash script.

Assume I have a set of command line arguments (CLA's) such as $1=2013 $2=03 $3=22 and I want to get the formatted date string for a date before, or afterward by some number of days.

I can always do, without the CLAs,

```
    date -d "20130322 -1 day" -u +%Y%m%d
```

but when I try something like,

```
    yyyy=2013
    month=03
    day=22
    yest='"'$yyyy$month$day'" -1 day"'
    yesterday=$(date -d $yest -u +%Y%m%d)
```

I get "date: invalid option -- '1'"

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: date isn't an environment variable.  It's a command, usually located in /bin.  Makes your subject title look confusing.  Looking at the body of your question, I think you mean "command line arguments" instead.

Comment: It really ends up a combination of the two. Sorry for the confusion. I usually don't code before the first pot of coffee...

Comment: If "CLA" means "command line argument", please update your question to use the complete phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you overcombined with quotes

```
pwadas@host:~$ echo $(date -d "20130322 -1 day" -u +%Y%m%d)
20130321
pwadas@host:~$ xx=20130322
pwadas@host:~$ echo $(date -d "$xx -1 day" -u +%Y%m%d)
20130321
pwadas@host:~$ 
pwadas@host:~$ yesterday=$(date -d "$xx -1 day" -u +%Y%m%d)
pwadas@host:~$ echo $yesterday
20130321
pwadas@host:~$
```

PS. above does not work with bash on MacOSX, but on Linux does..

Comment: It _can_ work on MacOS, if one installs GNU Date (with macports or such).

Comment: Thanks. That tests, now if I can make it work inside the script. I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Worked. Thanks for deconvoluting my logic.